# IMPORTRANGE query with checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I'm trying to do an IMPORTRANGE with query with checkbox. However I keep encountering parse error.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1pzzOzjtJ8GJOWnkBozdO0anKHnbeREvadEc4rzY4ezI",'Guest Speaker Tracking'!F4:O"),"select * where Col5=TRUE",1)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
'Guest Speaker Tracking'!F4:O"
```

by

```
"Guest Speaker Tracking!F4:O"
```

> Add a quotation character and remove apostrophes on the second argument of IMPORTRANGE